# Error using the function nf90_open of NetCDF4 in fortran

Tags: fortran, netcdf4

I am currently working on a big fortran code that I didn't write and
I am opening a Netcdf file with it. My file is called 0x0choc_merge.nc.
I am compiling my fortran code with ifort 2021.9.0 and am using netcdf/4.7.4.

I get the following error :

```
!!!!!!!!   NetCDF ERROR   !!!!!!!!
 Status :  2
 Message : Opening file (Read)
 : 0x0choc_merge.nc
```

Here is the line that tries to import the file :

```
status=nf90_open(trim(InName),nf90_nowrite,NC_Id)
__NETCDF_ERR('Opening file (Read): '//trim(InName))
```

where `InName` is "0x0choc_merge.nc", `nf90_nowrite` is worth 0 and
NC_Id is an integer.
if I look at `status` after the command `nf90_open`, it is worth 2.

My file is present in the directory, where I am running the code, so it doesn't seem to
me that the error is due to the non-existence of the file.

Does anyone know what this error stand for and how to overcome it?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: What about the access rights to the file?

Comment: Here are the access rights for the folder : ```-rw-r--r-- 1 (me) (server) 44998281 Jun 14 16:27 0x0choc_merge.nc``` The access rights doesn't seem to be the issue.